# How can I configure my route.rb page to redictect to a view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my route.rb file I currently have:

```
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
  map.root :controller => "test"
```

how do I direct my index page to direct to something like this:
  http://site.com/railstest/test/index.html

or just:
http://site.com/railstest/test.erb

originally it started off at: 
http://site.com/railstest/

which took me to the default html page, which has now been deleted. should I change the route or create a test.rb in the view folder, thank you

Comment: What would you want to see if you viewed a Ruby source file?

Comment: I want it to go the an html page note, source how do I get it to a page?

Comment: Still not sure what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to make a route that goes directly to a view, bypassing every controller.

So you have two options available to you now:

1. make it as a static html page

   - create the full html page
   - save it in /public/railstest/filename.html
   - use the URL: site.com/railstest/filename.html
   - note: hard to maintain, and cannot take advantage of layouts.
2. create a controller that will serve your view

   - either "script/generate RailstestController index" of "rails g PagesController index"
   - delete the app/views/index.html.erb that it creates and copy yourview file to that name instead
   - should Just Work